When ending a sentence by quoting a complete sentence which ends in a period, is there a period on each side of the final quotation mark?
What I'd find particularly helpful is an example in which we use the sentence about Alice and then follow it up with another sentence.
This whole concern stemmed from a concern about how such a sentence would interact with a sentence coming directly after it; my gut has always told me that the second sentence of a paragraph should always be directly preceded by a punctuation mark, not a quotation mark, but perhaps I just need to bite the bullet and get used to seeing sentences directly preceded by a quotation mark.

I've submitted this to be considered for reopening due to my concern that the linked question does not address the issue as to to why one option makes more sense than another when considering a circumstance in which the sentence is followed by another sentence. Of course, it's absolutely possible that I'm merely not seeing how the linked question addresses that concern, and in the event that that's the case I'd like to again apologize.

Which of the following is a grammatically correct complete sentence, assuming that the quoted statement is intended to itself also be a complete sentence?

Alice typed to Bob, "I use English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, too.".
Alice typed to Bob, "I use English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, too."
Alice typed to Bob, "I use English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, too".

My gut tells me that the second option would be problematic because if I have another sentence after this one then that sentence's first word would be directly preceded by a quotation mark instead of a period, and my intuition is that the second sentence of a paragraph should always be directly preceded by a punctuation mark, not a quotation mark. The first option seems sensible and I'm willing to place my bet on it. Am I right?
I'd like to apologize in advance if this happens to be a duplicate.
Something tells me it's probably been asked before.
While I'm placing bets, I'm also somewhat confident that the following are also grammatically correct:

Alice typed to Bob, "I use English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, too!".
Alice typed to Bob, "Do you use English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, too?".


Where have you ever seen anything but option 2 used?

@tchrist << Alice typed to Bob, "I use English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, too." whereas Bob typed to Alice the less satisfactory, "I use English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, too" (much to tchrist's annoyance). Exact quotes of written material can demand unfortunate punctuation.

The problem with this question is that, at its core, it is asking 'why one option makes more sense' than the others. That is a problem because most published writing is governed by the style manuals whose authors don't care whether the requirements they are imposing make sense; they seem to be more interested in what will look nice. People trained in logic and mathematics will readily agree with the OP that 1 makes the most sense, but unfortunately it would be difficult to find a style manual that recommends that version. We can't do anything about it other than deplore it.

I do happen to indeed be a math major. Perhaps that's why the issue bothered me so much in the first place.

Lynn G's answer in the linked duplicate seems to answer your question, especially in combination with the commentary here (and there).

At the risk of sounding a bit dull, I'd really love an explanation as to how Lynn G's answer in the linked duplicate addresses any potential concerns about following up the sentence about Alice with another sentence, particularly with regard to the matter of whether or not I just need to learn to accept the jarring conclusion that  follow-up sentences can be directly preceded by a closing quotation mark rather than a period.

I rationalize it like so, those speech mark (quotations) trapped between the two periods … Stack Exchange, too.". Delighted to learn of this… do not make a sentence.

@Joachim, several of the answers to both this and the other question state the conventions embodied in the style manuals, but none of them explains why these conventions make more sense than doing what is in OP's 1, which is what the question is about. LynnG's answer that you cite says that following one of the conventions will 'eliminate duplicate sentence-ending punctuation', and it seems that all the prevailing conventions aim at that. But why is that a good thing when multiple sentence-ending punctuation would well reflect the logical structure of what is said?

@jsw29 The question of 'why' one thing makes more sense than the other was edited in after the original question received answers, and was initially not part of it, so the proposed duplicate is still valid, IMO.

The obvious, and (I'd say) uncomplicated practice should be the first; however it is never used and the only current practice in AmE is "2". "1" takes into account the punctuation in two elements, the sentence, and the sentence that has been quoted in the sentence. It is in keeping with the punctuation practice  used often enough when the end punctuation in the quoted sentence is the interrogation mark, the exclamtion mark, or other, especially the semicolon. Those (?". // !". // ;".) are quite often found on the present site.
However, in the case of "full stop" (AmE, "period"), there is the same convention in both BrE and AmE of omitting the sentence end punctuation: only the quoted sentence is punctuated. As the practice  for using quotes  in both varieties of the language are different, reading such punctuation requires some care.

(CoGEL III.21) Quotation and quotaation marks […] Like parentheses, quotation marks can cooccur with other marks of
punctuation, but with some differences between AmE and BrE. AmE always
puts a period or a comma inside the closing quotation marks.

She enjoyed the article "Cities Are for Walking." (AmE)
She enjoyed the article 'Cities Are for Walking'. (BrE)


In both cases the full stop is punctuation for the sentence, not the quote (which, in this case, is a title and should not end with a full stop).
Thus, for AmE, in this example punctuation,

'the paragraph ends with "there is not enough time."',

the full stop does not apply to "there is not enough time", and it can be considered that the punctuation at the end is not part of the quote, but instead that it belongs  to the sentence (or clause) 'the paragraph ends with "there is not enough time"'.  The punctuation at the end of the paragraph must then  be inferred to be a full stop (or more rarely suspension dots, they do not end end with semicolons).
According to CoGEL, the sentence in AME, would be as follows.

Alice typed to Bob, "I use English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, too."

In BrE it would more likely be as below.

Alice typed to Bob, 'I use English Language & Usage Stack Exchange, too'.


These rules are arbitrary and prescriptive conventions and have nothing to do with the natural language per se. I'm surprised a grammar would devote attention to the subject.

@TimR You mean to say that the difference between AmE and BrE as made salient in CoGEL has no substantial reality?

Are we supposed to know what CoGEL is?  Every result on the first page of my recent search related to the Council on Governmental Ethics Laws, which I doubt is what you have in mind.

@phoog Not really, unless there were on the ELU a section where admitted abbreviations are consigned, which would help, I think.  CoGEL is A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, Quirk et al (abbreviation due to user LPH, but there might be other abbreviations (in particular "CGEL")), to be differentiated from "CGEL", The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language, Huddleston & Pullum (much used on the present site),  abbreviation used in almost all cases.

If one is writing to an examination board asking for a decision on punctuation, the original must be put within the inverted commas (or guillemets) no matter how it was punctuated. Accuracy has to trump style recommendations.

@EdwinAshworth I notice that you use "<<, >>"; are those what you call "guillemets", and do you consider them as merely alternative symbols to "«, »" (French quotation marks, called in French "guillemets")? Do they take on a special function in English (besides that of being used for a third level of quote)? Perhaps they are a personal usage of yours. I find no information on their use in the English language.

I use them in 'comments' here (better formatting, eg bulleting, is available in answers)  where inverted commas are already in use or about to be used (and perhaps elsewhere where I feel inverted commas might be misunderstood; scare quotes have many usages). I use the chevrons rather than search for the correct orthographic.

I'm saying that such vagaries of punctuation are not a linguistic development per se but an artificial, prescriptive, typographic convention, and for that reason I'm surprised to see the topic addressed in a grammar.  Please  tell me they don't talk about one space or two between sentences.

Your first option is never correct. A period is a period. You cannot have multiple.
Your second option is correct in American English, where periods always precede the closing quotation mark. So whether the quoted material is a full sentence or not is irrelevant; the period (or a comma) would be placed inside.
Your third option might be correct in British English, which (as I have gathered) places punctuation based on whether it was part of the original quote or not. So, for BrE, if what she typed included the period, it would be inside; if not, it would be outside as in option three.
As for your question/exclamation mark examples: again, I think it would depend on   which style you follow. In AmE, periods are subsumed by any other form of terminal punctuation. So there should be nothing following the closing quotation mark. In BrE, however, I believe they would follow the same basic idea as option 3 and add a period.

Consider 'The reply "It's a bomb!" is found on the next page.'; if the exclamation mark subsumes a period after the second quote, there is an error. It follows that it can't do that by itself, and that it has to be so as a function of the text that follows (if there is a new paragraph after, if the text that follows in the same paragraph starts with a capital letter, …).

I've found and see as sensible a style guide allowing say << "Was what David actually said 'You're going to the cinema?'?" >> in 'BrE' usage (whatever that really means).

@EdwinAshworth It seems to be within the bounds of reasonnable embeddings, "reasonnable" meaning "not having too many levels of embedding". This question in a question seems clear to me; it is  somewhat difficult in the spoken language because of the coincidence of two raising intonations, but the rise starts on "what"  I think,
